# Equivalent of oracle function DBMS_LOB.SUBSTRING in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, oracle

Is there any equivalent for the Oracle DBMS function `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTRING` on Mysql?
if not how can I get the text of  BLOB in MYSQL server? (I only need to use SQL no other programming languages)

Comment: Iirc, the docs say that `SUBSTRING` can be applied to a `{LONG|MEDIUM}(BLOB|TEXT)` column in the same way as to `VARCHAR2` columns. If you treat `BLOB`s as text, you'll probably have to set the character set somewhere.

Comment: ```SELECT SUBSTR(column_name, start, length) from table_name;```

Answer (score 1):

Please try dbms_lob.substr which is equivalent to DBMS_LOB.SUBSTRING

Comment: "FUNCTION dbms_lob.substr does not exist. Check the Function Name Parsing and Resolution section in the Reference Manual"

Answer (score 0):

Get the Oracle value passed to dbms_lob.substr and prefix the value with 0x without quotes for the MySQL insert statement.

I did tried for my case and succeeded.